# Run only foreground service when app is closed to reduce memory usage

Tags: java, android, service, broadcastreceiver

I am running a foreground service via broadcast receiver on boot completed.
It starts the services as desired and take only a a fraction of the device memory use and when I launch the app it increased the device memory usage as it should but when I close the app it still takes too much of memory even though the app has been closed and only the foreground service is running. What I want is really that it should use the same amount of memory after app has been closed as of it was using before the app was opened.

So, I did some digging through Android Profiler and what I found is that when foreground service starts after the boot it only opens `Application.class`, `BroadcastReceiver.class`, `Service.class` and few other background classes. And as I open the app it opens all the above classes and other activities . But when I close the app it still uses the device memory for graphic supports. I don't know how to stop that memory usage after the app has been closed.

Here are some screenshots of my **Android Profiler**

**Before Launching the App through Foreground Notification** Memory used 65MB

remember the foreground notification was started from the broadcast receiver after boot complete.
[image: before launching the app]

**After Launching the app from Notifications** Memory used 146 MB
[image: after launching app]

**While surfing through activities** Memory used 165 MB
[image: surfing through activities]

**After app has been closed** Memory used 140 MB
[image: after app closed]

Now I want to know how to achieve the task of using the previous amount of memory use that was 65MB?

Here are my BroadcastReceiver and Service.class code.

**Broadcast Receiver**

```
public class BootCompletedIntentListener extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED".equals(intent.getAction())){
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context,ClipMonitorService.class);
        ContextCompat.startForegroundService(context,serviceIntent);
    }
}
}
```

**Service**

```
public class ClipMonitorService extends Service {
private static final String TAG = "ClipboardManager";

private ExecutorService mThreadPool = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
private ClipboardManager mClipboardManager;
private PrefManager prefManager;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    prefManager = new PrefManager(this);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (mClipboardManager != null) {
        mClipboardManager.removePrimaryClipChangedListener(
                mOnPrimaryClipChangedListener);
    }
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

    Intent settingIntent = new Intent(this, SettingActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pendingSettIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, settingIntent, 0);

    RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.custom_notification_layout);
    remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.btn_action, pendingSettIntent);
    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.notif_subtitle, "1 Clips copied Today");


    Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round)
            .setContent(remoteViews)
            .setVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_SECRET)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MIN)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary))
            .setShowWhen(false)
            .build();

    startForeground(1, notification);
    mClipboardManager =
            (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
    mClipboardManager.addPrimaryClipChangedListener(
            mOnPrimaryClipChangedListener);

    return START_STICKY;
}

private ClipboardManager.OnPrimaryClipChangedListener mOnPrimaryClipChangedListener =
        new ClipboardManager.OnPrimaryClipChangedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrimaryClipChanged() {
                Log.d(TAG, "onPrimaryClipChangeds");

                try {

                    String textToPaste = mClipboardManager.getPrimaryClip().getItemAt(0).getText().toString();

                    if (textToPaste.length() > 200) {
                        if (prefManager.isClipNotifOns()) {
                            mThreadPool.execute(new MakeNotifRunnable(
                                    textToPaste));

                        }

                    }
                } catch (Exception ignored) {

                }


            }
        };

private class MakeNotifRunnable implements Runnable {
    private final CharSequence mTextToWrite;

    public MakeNotifRunnable(CharSequence text) {
        mTextToWrite = text;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Intent notifIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PostNewsActivity.class);
        notifIntent.putExtra("post", mTextToWrite);

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        int notificationId = 2;
        String channelId = "channel1";
        String channelName = "Clipboard Monitor Notification";
        int importance = 0;
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT;
        }

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel mChannel = new NotificationChannel(
                    channelId, channelName, importance);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
        }

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(), channelId)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round)
                .setContentTitle("Verify copied content")
                .setContentText(mTextToWrite)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setOnlyAlertOnce(true);

        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(getApplicationContext());
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(notifIntent);
        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
                0,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
        );
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

        notificationManager.notify(notificationId, mBuilder.build());
    }
}
}
```

Help me to reduce memory usage
I'll be thankful for your answer.
P.S: As I am new to android development I may have uploaded too much information with jargons .Pardon me for that.